# Passing a ManagedContext with Core Date + Magical Record

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

Currently I'm setting my NSManagedContext's by doing the following in ViewDidLoad:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
```

**.m**

```
 viewDidLoad {
 _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
 }
```

**Question**: Do I have to pass this same managed context to all of my subsequent viewcontrollers that I want to have access to this ManagedContexts, or can I write a new `@property` for each new viewcontroller's .h and then set each new viewcontrollers ManagedObject in .m with `_managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Core Data stack is set up, MagicalRecord creates a default context of the "main queue concurrency type". If all your view controllers use this default context, you can

- (1) pass the context around from one view controller to the next,
- (2) call `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]` in each view controller to get the 
  default context,

and you *could* also, as you currently do

- (3) call `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]` in `viewDidLoad` to get the default context.

But the last method works only because `viewDidLoad` is always called on the main thread and
`MR_contextForCurrentThread` returns the default context in that case.

However, `MR_contextForCurrentThread` creates additional contexts (of the private queue concurrency type) if called from a non-main
thread, and associates the context with a fixed `NSThread`. But, as @casademora correctly said, such a private queue context does not always use the same thread for each 
operation. So `MR_contextForCurrentThread` should not be used on a non-main thread,
and it is identical to `MR_defaultContext` if called from the main thread.

Therefore, even if it works in your case, you should avoid method (3). Whether you choose
method (1) or (2) is purely a matter of taste.

If you need an additional context, e.g. for background import operations, you can call
e.g. `MR_context` or `MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator` and pass that context to whereever
it is needed.

Comment: Great thank you so much for taking the time to write a thoughtful answer. I understand this somewhat better now :)

Comment: @MartinR Why should MR_contextForCurrentThread not be called for background operations ? Don't we use private queue concurrency type to save background changes with the parent context (main thread context in this case) ? [Assuming we want a different context for that thread]

Comment: @user1349663: A private queue MOC uses a separate dispatch *queue* and there is no 1-1 correspondence between *queues* and *threads*.

Answer (score 0):

Please stop using contextForCurrentThread. This goes doubly for using GCD queues. While GCD queues are implemented on top of the threading model, you are **not guaranteed** to get the same actual thread for every subsequent block.

If you need a new context, create a new private queue, main queue, or confinement context.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how I would create a new private queue? Does it make sense to instantiate one for the entire app and then pass this que around to various controllers accordingly?

Comment: Yes, how would that private queue look like?

Comment: Possible to create another MOC on the main thread to use when you are making/listening for UI updates?  Then throw that away if update/edits are cancelled?