# Editing a Custom Object with Core Data and Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

IF I have a List object and a ListItem object, and the List has a one-to-many relationship with ListItem's, what seems like best design to edit a list? I fetch the list with

```
// Find the list we're supposed to edit
        temporaryList = [List MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"uniqueID" withValue:_editingListID];
```

and can then update its simple properties such as name

```
        temporaryList.name = @"new name";
```

however I'm wondering how best to update its listItems. It is stored in an NSSet as per the Core Data structure, and I store each ListItem with the following when creating a new list.

```
ListItem *listItem = [ListItem MR_createInContext:_managedObjectContext];
```

So, when I go to edit the contents of a List, I'd like to reset its NSSet of ListItems

```
// something like
list.contents = nil;
list.contents = mynewarrayoflistitems
```

But then I also need a way to delete the old ListItems that were saved in memory. How should I go about this? My first thought was to delete the list that's being edited (which will cause a casacade effect to occur and will delete all of the ListItems with it, and then reset all of the list's contents, name, id, etc.. Is this best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed,  the cascading delete rule is only applied when an object is *deleted*. For example, if `list` is deleted then all related `listItem` objects are also deleted.

If `contents` is the to-many relationship from `List` to `ListItem`, then

```
list.contents = nil;
```

does not apply any delete rule and does not delete the formerly related objects.

But you can go the other way around: If the delete rule for the inverse relationship
from `List` to `ListItem` is set to "Nullify", then deleting a list item will remove
it from the relationship, so you can iterate over `list.contents` and delete all related
objects.

This has the advantage that the `List` object itself is preserved. Then you can create
new items and add them to the list.

Comment: also would you mind taking a quick look at a related Core Data question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814656/passing-a-managedcontext-with-core-date-magical-record